# (Xubuntu) - How to turn off Laptop screen while external screen is connected

Tags: multiple-monitors, xubuntu, laptop, display, external-monitor

Hi I just installed Xubuntu on my Laptop, now I want it to disable the laptop screen as long as the external screen is connected. But when I disconnect the external monitor I want the laptop screen to be activated again. How can I configure xubuntu to work this way? 
I have a nvidia graphics card and an intel chipset in my laptop. Hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: when I simply disable the laptop screen output, the screen doesnt turn on automatically after unplugging the external screen, so thats no good..

Comment: So, you want HDMI hot-plugging! Just like usb hot-plugging! I don't think that's possible yet. At least not by default. Maybe ... with some custom-made complicated script.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you run the following in Terminal and while your laptop is connected to the external monitor and both screens are displaying?

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --off
```

Comment: Do you know how to turn it back on again?

Answer (score 0):

I used the guide in here to do exactly this a few days ago:
https://charlesmcruz.wordpress.com/2012/01/22/ubuntu-11-10-automatic-hdmi-toggle-with-audio/

Only had to change the sound profile for it to work perfectly. When I connect an hdmi cable, the display turns off on my laptop and moves to the monitor and the sound changes as well.
When I disconnect it, it returns everything to it's previous state.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: It's still available on the wayback machine: https://askubuntu.com/questions/305024/xubuntu-how-to-turn-off-laptop-screen-while-external-screen-is-connected/575097?noredirect=1#comment2004797_575097

and here is a txt backup of the page just in case: https://workupload.com/file/8jBmMY6Q